# How to do awk comparison in TCL

Tags: tcl

How to use `awk 'FNR==NR{a[$2];next}!($2 in a)' a b` in tcl.

When I ran this using `exec awk {FNR==NR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)} m1 m2 > DIFF`, its giving out nothing in `DIFF`.

I want to compare `m1` and `m2` file and different should be dump in `DIFF`.

Comment: You have the correct quoting. Do the files exist in the current directory?

Comment: For "lines in m2 that are not in m1" use [`comm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/comm.1.html): `exec comm -13 m1 m2 > DIFF`

Comment: Where's the tcl here?  This looks like a shell script.  Why the backquotes?

Comment: The backquotes were from a bad edit that changed the OP's code